# Windows Reset to erase Linux on dual boot machine

Tags: windows, ubuntu

I have Ubuntu in dual boot laptop. I want to know if I can use the Windows reset that supposedly restores the computer to factory settings to delete that partition?

Answer (score 1):

Recovery won't probably even work anymore, it's quicker to follow this http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/20864-mbr-restore-windows-7-master-boot-record.html and then remove the linux partitions with disk management.